# Android kernal based on which system?

Tags: android, ubuntu

I'm working on Android and I'm studying about kernel. Now, I heard that android kernel based on Ubuntu and some of my fellow workers is telling me it's not Ubuntu. Can anyone answer this to clear my query?

Comment: Android and Ubuntu both use Linux kernel. But they don't have anything else in common. And Linux kernel is optimized differently for those systems.

Comment: Hi, Ubuntu is base on Linux Kernel Like Android, GoodLuck

Answer (score 0):

Both Android and Ubuntu use the Linux kernel.

However, Android uses a special fork of the kernel.

The default releases of Ubuntu also have a custom version, but they are compatible with kernels compiled from Linux source.

In case of Android, you will have to use the kernel sources provided by the manufacturer. If you use kernel sources of a similar device of the same manufacturer, it will probably have a lot of non-operational hardware, if it boots at all. Sources from other OEMs will almost never boot.

Basically, Ubuntu is a Linux distribution, while Android is a separate OS that shares some code with Linux systems.

Answer (score 0):

Android is a mobile operating system developed by Google. It is based on a modified version of the Linux kernel and other open source software, and is designed primarily for touchscreen mobile devices such as smartphones and tablets. In addition, Google has further developed Android TV for televisions, Android Auto for cars, and Wear OS for wrist watches, each with a specialized user interface. Variants of Android are also used on game consoles, digital cameras, PCs and other electronics.

**It's basically a modified version of the Linux kernel and not a specific version or edition of Linux.**
You can check the Wikipedia Page for more information.
[wikipedia Android operating_system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

Answer (score 0):

Android's kernal based on one of the Linux's kernal long term support (LTS) branches.